# Type-safe Backus-Naur-Form DSL with semantic actions in C#

Tags: c#

I want to make a little domain specific language in C# for a parser generator. Suppose, as an example, that I used it to make a simple calculator. I want to be able to do something like this (but in C#):

```
TERM ::= NUMBER PLUS TERM { (a,b) => a+b }
```

So there are two kinds of symbols, ones that have a value (like *NUMBER* & *TERM*) and others that don't (like *PLUS*). I can define those using two classes:

```
class Symbol {}
class Symbol<T> {}

Symbol PLUS;
Symbol<double> NUMBER, TERM;
```

How can I define the production rules in a type safe manner?
I could have a function like this:

```
Production Prod<T1,T2,TR>(Symbol<TR> head, Symbol<T1> s1, Symbol s2, Symbol<T2> s3, Func<T1,T2,TR> action);

// Declare the grammar:
var productions = new Production[] { Prod(TERM, NUMBER, PLUS, TERM, (a,b) => a+b), ... };
```

But I would have to have 2<sup>n+1</sup> such functions (where *n* is the maximum number of symbols in a production rule), one for each possible sequence of `Symbol`'s and `Symbol<T>`'s.

*[Edit]*

I could have something like this:

```
class Void {}
Symbol<Void> PLUS;

Production Prod<T1,T2,T3,TR>(Symbol<TR> head, Symbol<T1> s1, Symbol<T2> s2, Symbol<T3> s3, Func<T1,T2,T3,TR> action);

var rule = Prod(TERM,NUMBER,PLUS,TERM,(a,b,c) => a+c); // no _ for b in C# 6.
```

That would only require *n* such functions.

*[/Edit]*

I've also considered using operator overloading, but they can't have generics, so something like this is not going to work:

```
var rule = TERM | NUMBER | PLUS | NUMBER | (a,b) => a+b;
```

I suppose I could use generic methods. Like this:

```
var rule = TERM.P(NUMBER).P(PLUS).P(NUMBER).A((a,b) => a+b);
```

But that's kind of ugly. Are there some other tricks that might work and not look so horrible?

Note: I don't need to keep the types in the `Production` class, I'm fine having `object` at that stage. I would just like to avoid manually adding types to the semantic actions and/or having dummy placeholder arguments for non-value symbols.

**Note 2:** It needs to work with C# 6 and `dynamic` won't work for me.

**[Edit]**: And I can't really use external libraries. I've already implemented an Earley parser, so this is just about expressing the grammar conveniently for it.

Comment: If you need to make a DSL, have you taken a look at `Antlr`?  It's made for this sort of thing, though maybe its overkill here.

Comment: Why not use F# and a parser combinator library like FParsec? There are C# parser combinator libraries like Sprache and Pidgin, but the resulting parser definitions aren't as clean as those created by FParsec

Comment: @Amy I don't want to actually generate code. Otherwise I'd just use something like Antlr.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It has to be C# version 6. Don't ask why. ;) Also, I can't really use a big library. But I'll look into those two, if I get some ideas.

Comment: Most libraries use an arithmetic expression parser as an example. [This is a Pidgin expression parser](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Pidgin/blob/master/Pidgin.Examples/Expression/ExprParser.cs), a similar one [with Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache/blob/develop/samples/LinqyCalculator/ExpressionParser.cs)

Comment: As for FParsec, the resulting parsers are so small, it's hard to find a standalone example - [in this example](https://gist.github.com/mausch/760445/c039d42dd446d648cb07b55fc38323a677b56c29#file-mathparser-fs-L13) the parser is just 9 lines, the rest of the example compares this to a hand-written recursive parser. It's a *lot* cleaner than the other parsers too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think Pidgin is a good example of what I want to avoid.